# Does the block size issue also apply to Dogecoin?

Tags: dogecoin, blocksize

Looking at https://bitinfocharts.com/ I see that Dogecoin has only 13% of the number of transactions per day that Bitcoin has (12,778 vs 94,166). I understand that makes block sizes less of an issue for Dogecoin.

Is that the only reason why I've never seen Dogecoiners partaking in debates about block sizes, or do they have some other reason for not worrying about this yet?

Answer (score 5):

It has been [discussed before](https://www.reddit.com/r/dogecoin/comments/3cg31l/block_size_and_transaction_confirmations_for/), but you're right that the problem isn't nearly as big. There are a couple of reasons for this:

1. Dogecoin has the [same blocksize limit](https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=MAX_BLOCK_SIZE) as Bitcoin, but it has ten times as many blocks, and therefore the limit is ten times higher.
2. As you say, there are fewer transactions on Dogecoin's network.
3. Hard forks are regarded differently within the Dogecoin community. For example, they recently altered their coin to remove the one hundred million coin cap. I don't think the Dogecoin devs would have any compunctions about raising the 1MB limit.

Comment: Great response! However, re: your point '3', my understanding is that the 100 billion coin cap was never actually in the code, although this wasn't realised until a few days after launch. So there was never a hard fork to get rid of the cap, but rather a passive decision to leave things as they were. See, for instance, https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/issues/23#issuecomment-33893149.